# Embedded Rust on a pi 4

Tags: rust, embedded, raspberry-pi4, toolchain

im a beginner in embedde rust on a raspberry pi. Need some help for loading code via toolchain on the pi 4. Tanks for helping

i hope someone can help me with that or show me where i can get a guide

Comment: RPi runs Linux - you don't need embedded rust for that.  Or do you mean you are developing for an embedded device with the RPi as a development host?  Also _"Need some help for loading code via toolchain on the pi 4._" needs some elaboration.  It is not clear what that could mean in the context of the rest of the question.

Comment: Perhaps this is what you need: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/embedded-rust-programming-on-raspberry-pi-zero-w/. It refers to RPi ZeroW with a PC development host, but is probably applicable to any RPi, it is simply that the RPi Zero is a bit underpowered for comfortable self-hosted development.

Comment: tahnks buddy, thats waht i was looking for :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZT8APrzvc4&t=975s). It also goes over gpio.